# REST Services for push notification in MFP 7.1 - Issue

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

We develop hybrid mobile app using Ionic framework. We need to send push notification to the users using MFP 7.1. So using RestAPI, we are trying for that. We follow the steps given in this tutorial.
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/c_restapi_runtime.html

Sample code:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://example.com:10080/myproject/imfpush/v1/apps/com_ibm_tagpushv2/messages");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response;
 try {
            response = client.execute(httpPost);
            System.out.println("Response-->"+response);
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           System.out.println("Exception has occurred");
     }
```

My application id is com_ibm_tagpushv2.

Error:

```
Connection to https://example.com:10080 refused
```

Kindly help.

Comment: I'm assuming that you have replaced the real host name in place of the 'example.com' and your project name for the 'myproject'.  It is obvious but sometime can be overlooked :)  Have you try with the http with the port that your server is listening instead?  9080 is the default for Liberty server.

Comment: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://example.com:9080 refused.                                                     This is what I get when I use this URL  https://example.com:9080/myproject/imfpush/v1/apps/com_ibm_tagpushv2/devices?"

Comment: Is the Java code running on the same machine as the MFP server? If not , are you sure there are no connectivity issues or firewalls blocking the request? Connection refused could be because there is nothing listening at the ip and port. Or possibly a firewall between client & server that is blocking the connection.

Comment: Yes java code is running on the same machine. We dont have any firewall restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

To send push notification in MFP 7.1 use below RestAPI

http://example.com:10080/myproject/imfpush/v1/apps/com.ibm.Notifications/messages

For more details please refer

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_send_message_post.html

Thanks.

Comment: I used the URL given by you to send the message. I am getting the following error  :  org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://example.com:10080 refused

Comment: I am assuming that you are using real host name and app name. Please share complete error message from log.

Comment: I have edited my question with updated URL and error.

Comment: Your connection is "HTTPS" meaning the server is rejecting it as you are not authorized to access it's resources. You even need to include the certificate in your connection or you need to allow all HTTPS calls ( The 2nd approach is not recommended.